# Get Organization of a PAT Azure DevOps API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Given an Azure Devops Personal Access Token having access to only 1 Organization, is it possible to fetch which Organization it has access to using the API? Like an introspection endpoint?

Notes:

- there is an endpoint [listing accounts of a specific user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/account/accounts/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP) but this requires a PAT with access **to all organization** (although it is not documented) which is too permissive for my usecase
- there is the endpoint [listing tokens of the account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tokenadmin/personal-access-tokens/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP) but it requires a specific tokenAdministration scope which too permissive for my usecase

Comment: As far as I know, PATs are opaque; unlike JWTs, for example, you can't read *any* information from the raw token. If you've lost any record of its organisation and scope, I think the only thing you can do is to try the token in practice, and see where it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my knowledge there is currently no direct way to know which organization a PAT has access to.

There are two workarounds you can refer to:

1. Using this REST API [Pats - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tokens/pats/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP) to list all PATs in one organization. You need to use OAuth authentication. Then check if your current PAT is in it.
2. As Vince Bowdren said, use your PAT to try to access the organization, like call some REST APIs, then you know which organization the PAT belongs to. But this is not necessarily successful, because it is related to the scope of your PAT. For example, your PAT belongs to an organization, but the scope of your PAT does not meet the requirements of the API you use.